# Building multiple branches with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration

I have a project in Gitlab where I have a master branch and many feature branches for every modification. Right now jenkins builds codes from master branch and deploys it via ssh to a virtual server.

Is there and option in Jenkins (similar to the one in Hudson) to get my jenkins job to build master and other (chosen by me) feature branches, compile them to one and then deploy to the server via ssh?

Comment: How do you expect Jenkins to resolve potential merge conflicts? Automatically?

Comment: Eventual merge conflicts would be resolved od gitlab level, so we can assume there won't be any